# Postgresql: create a text field with unique values case insensitive, citext vs nondeterministic collation

Tags: postgresql, collation

I have to store email addresses in a field of a table of a Postgres database and I need them to be unique in the table, case insensitive unique.

The two approach that I found:

Using citext extension:

```
create table test (
 -- other fields
 email citext not null
);
create unique index ux1 on test(email);
```

Using non-deterministic collations:

```
create collation nd (
 provider = 'icu',
 locale = 'und-u-ks-level2',
 deterministic = false
);

create table test (
 -- other fields
 email text not null collate nd
);
create unique index ux1 on test(email);
```

What is the best/preferred approach ?
I am also not sure if in the collation one I used the right locale, if someone can confirm or it's better `und-u-ks-level1`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? New to Pg. Have aways used mssql and mysql and asked Google this exact same question to find this